# 'style=text-indent' interferes with 'foreach'

Tags: html, css

I have a foreach routine, that should gives me all the Task names of an area. It's also possible to make the  foldout for each of this Tasks.
So Long, so good. As soon as I try to indent the  with the command "text-indent:" it overjumps every second of my elements.

Here my code that produces the error:

```
$T_Select->execute(array(1));
foreach ($T_Select as $Task){
   $Rechte->execute(array($Task['id_T']));
   $Amount = $Rechte->rowCount();
   $returnName = $Task['T_Name'];
   echo '<br><details style="text-indent:10px;><summary><mark>'.$returnName.'</mark></summary>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Noch keine Rechte vergeben!!!<br></details>';
}
```

Following the mysql Select (that is ok):

```
$T_Select = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT DISTINCT T_Name, id_T FROM Tasks WHERE id_B = ?");
```

Following the Output of the Console:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT T_Name, id_T FROM Tasks WHERE id_B = 1;
+----------------------------------------+------+
| T_Name                                 | id_T |
+----------------------------------------+------+
| ACT Zentrierung                        |    1 |
| Ausgangstellung Topf auf / ab          |    2 |
| Stoppposition Topf auf /ab             |    3 |
| Greifer                                |    4 |
| Topfkonus                              |    5 |
| Topfkeil                               |    6 |
| Kette für Schalteranschlagvorrichtung  |    7 |
| Versorgungsspannung für Motor          |    8 |
| Alle Schrauben und Verbindungen        |    9 |
+----------------------------------------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now the Output on my Website:

```
ACT Status
   ▶Ausgangstellung Topf auf / ab
   ▶Greifer
   ▶Topfkeil
   ▶Versorgungsspannung für Motor
   ▶Werkzeugwechsel
   ▶Topf auf / ab
   ▶Schalteraktion
```

As you can see, only every second item appears. However, this isn´t the case if I dont use

```
style=text-indent:10px
```

Here the code without it:

```
    $T_Select->execute(array(1));
foreach ($T_Select as $Task){
   $Rechte->execute(array($Task['id_T']));
   $Amount = $Rechte->rowCount();
   $returnName = $Task['T_Name'];
   echo '<br><details><summary><mark>'.$returnName.'</mark></summary>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Noch keine Rechte vergeben!!!<br></details>';
}
```

And the new Output:

```
ACT Status
▶ACT Zentrierung
▶Ausgangstellung Topf auf / ab
▶Stoppposition Topf auf /ab
▶Greifer
▶Topfkonus
▶Topfkeil
▶Kette für Schalteranschlagvorrichtung
▶Versorgungsspannung für Motor
▶Alle Schrauben und Verbindungen
```

My question is: How can I indent the  items, without messing with my Output.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but are you missing a closing `"` after `10px`? Here: `style="text-indent:10px;`

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.

Unfortunately I don´t know how to mark your answer as correct.